# play framework runs all DOWN scripts of evolutions then applying all UPs in reverse order which destructs tables

Tags: playframework, orm, ebean, playframework-2.3

I am using play framework and wondering a problem in evolutions. After I changed my models (e.g. add a field), I prepare proper sql script (both for UPs and DOWNs) e.g. 3.sql (assuming I have already 2 evolution scripts) and put in related folder.

But the play shows me this message:

> Database 'default' needs evolution!
>
> # !!! WARNING! This script contains DOWNS evolutions that are likely
>   destructive
>
> # --- Rev:2,Downs - 3ee3d8e
>
> ALTER TABLE my_table DROP COLUMN low_priority;
>
> # --- Rev:1,Downs - 4f92dc6
>
> [ a long script which drops all tables!]
>
> # --- Rev:1,Ups - 5501951
>
> [ a long script creating tables ] # --- Rev:2,Ups - 3ee3d8e
>
> ALTER TABLE my_tableADD COLUMN low_priority tinyint(1) default 0
>   not null;
>
> # --- Rev:3,Ups - 397ada5 ALTER TABLE my_table CHANGE COLUMN
>   low_priority lowpriority TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ;

Why play (and actually its ORM : EBean) behaves this way? It should just run "UPs" of 3.sql (last evolution script) and not roll back through history!

P.S. I am speaking about my dev instance (As the above is not happening in PROD). But for some reasons I must have some heavy data in my dev DB and doing a "backup&restore" each time really takes time.

Answer (score 0):

I founded why this happens. According to this [link](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/8HoNAE5KTxo/qEELGxCC3P0J):

> In play 2.2 different evolutions are checked from first to last: first
>   1.sql is checked against evolution 1 in db, then 2, 3 and so on. If some pair differs, all evolutions sgarting from different will need to
>   be downgraded and upgraded. In previous versions of play evolutions
>   were checked from last to first-equal, so if your last evolutions were
>   equal, other evolutions were not checked.
>
> After this two changes play finds first evolutions with different
>   whitespace and asks to reapply them.